# Get top 1 max row of more than 1 order_id

Tags: sql, oracle11g, greatest-n-per-group

This code below works for getting the last updated row for OrderNumber 10346497 which is what I wanted.

But now I need to get EVERY order in my table with the last time it was updated.  So if i comment out  "where ordernumber = '10346497' then it only returns one row but I want all rows with just the last time it was updated.
Appreciate the help!

```
  SELECT * FROM (
                  SELECT WH1.*, row_number() over(order by ORDERDATETIME desc) RN
                  FROM WH_ORDERS_REPORT WH1
                  WHERE ORDERNUMBER = '10346497'
                  )
  WHERE RN = 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to partition by the ordernumber, this will "restart" the numbering for each order

```
select * 
from (
  select wh.*, 
         row_number() over (partition by wh.ordernumber order by wh.orderdatetime desc) rn
  from wh_orders_report wh
)
where rn = 1
```

Comment: I believe this works. I will continue to test and verify. thank you.